# how to pass parameters by reference in matlab function

Tags: matlab, reference

i'm a beginner in matlab and i want to calculate the sum of product of every possible combination of elements of a (3*n) matrix that are picked from different row.

for example if the matrix is x = [1 2 3 , 4 5 6] i want the result of 
D = 1*4 + 1*5 + 1*6 + 2*4 + 2*5 + 2*6 + 3*4 + 3*5 + 3*6.

I wrote the following recursive code but i'm having problem with passing a variable by reference.

```
function combination(n,A,x) % n= number of rows ,A= empty array, x = the matrix  
    if n == 0
    D = D + prod(A); 
    else
        for i = 1:1:3
            A = [A x(n,i)];
            combination(n-1,A,x);
            if length(A)>=1
                A = A(1:length(A)-1);
            end 
       end
   end
end
```

i need the D parameter but when i declare D as global it doesn't help. 
is there anyway in matlab that i could pass D by reference in function and get the result at the end?
thanks in advance.
sorry for my english.

Comment: If you want to read about a relatively advanced way to do this, see [handle classes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you just use `prod(sum(x,2))`? I think if you rearrange the terms in your sum, you'll see that you can just multiply the sums of your rows together and you'll get the same thing. (But perhaps I've misunderstood exactly what you're looking for).

For example:

```
>> x=[1 2 3 ; 4 5 6; 7,8,9]
x =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
>> prod(sum(x,2))
ans =
        2160
>> 1*4*7 + 1*4*8 + 1*4*9 + 1*5*7 + 1*5*8 + 1*5*9 + 1*6*7 + 1*6*8 + 1*6*9 + 2*4*7 + 2*4*8 + 2*4*9 + 2*5*7 + 2*5*8 + 2*5*9 + 2*6*7 + 2*6*8 + 2*6*9 + 3*4*7 + 3*4*8 + 3*4*9 + 3*5*7 + 3*5*8 + 3*5*9 + 3*6*7 + 3*6*8 + 3*6*9
ans =
        2160
```

If you really need to do this recursively, using a combinatory approach, you should be able to just pass in D as an input and also return it as an output of your function, something like this:

```
function D = combination(n,A,x, D) % n= number of rows ,A= empty array, x = the matrix  
    if n == 0
    D = D + prod(A); 
    else
        for i = 1:1:3
            A = [A x(n,i)];
            D = combination(n-1,A,x, D);
            if length(A)>=1
                A = A(1:length(A)-1);
            end 
       end
   end
end
```

and then call it initially with `D` equal to zero.

Don't worry about passing by reference here. MATLAB doesn't have pass by reference (it has variables that have reference semantics, but that's a different thing), but it uses copy-on-write, and has special optimizations for calculations that can be done in-place, as your calculation with `D` can here.

Comment: Indeed, a call like `A=func(A)` is optimized for the function to work in-place, but only if the function is defined with `function A=func(A)`. That is, the same variable must be used both as input and output, and both in the function definition and when calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring it as global does the job, however, you should pass it as input, and return it as output.

MATLAB will take care of not making a copy if your code does not need a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you write in the function definition:

```
function D = combination(n,A,x,D)
D = D + something
end
```

your function can be called by:

output = combination(n_in,A_in,x_in
the recursion follows the same so instead of calling

```
combination(n-1, A,x)
```

you write

```
D = combination(n-1,A,x,D)
```

and go on in your code.

I hope this helps you, and maybe there is a Matlab own function that can handle this task already but I am not sure.

Comment: but OP's code is `D=D+...` so he needs it as input also